# Oracle get unique year and month in query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have following query that returns the results that i am looking for except for fact i am not able to get group by to work:

```
select EXTRACT(month from datetime_insert) m, 
       EXTRACT(year from datetime_insert) y 
  from tst_result_main 
 order by datetime_insert
```

This returns following:

```
m    y
1    2006
1    2006
2    2006
2    2006
2    2007
2    2007
```

Results i am looking for:

```
m    y
1    2006
2    2006
2    2007
```

I have tried following which throws error:

```
select EXTRACT(month from datetime_insert) m,
       EXTRACT(year from datetime_insert) y 
  from tst_result_main 
 order by datetime_insert group by y, m
```

error:

```
 ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
 00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
 *Cause:    
 *Action: Error at Line: 7 Column: 136
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: First things first: You can't have a GROUP BY clause **after** ORDER BY. They teach this in the first **hour** of intro SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
select EXTRACT(month from datetime_insert) m, EXTRACT(year from datetime_insert) y 
  from tst_result_main 
 group by EXTRACT(year from datetime_insert), EXTRACT(month from datetime_insert)
 order by y,m;
```

An alias can not be used for a `group by` expression.

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d5caa/2)

Comment: why you are using group by without aggregation function  .. use distinct

Comment: the ways related to `distinct` is also possible, all ways go to Rome ...

Comment: do the fact you are not using aggregation function you should use  distinct and not group by  the use of group by without aggregation function is deprecated  in SQL .

Comment: @scaisEdge `group by` provides distinction, then i don't think i should include an extra `distinct` clause in addition to that.

Answer (score 6):

Did you tried something like DISTINCT values:

```
select DISTINCT
    EXTRACT(month from datetime_insert) m
    , EXTRACT(year from datetime_insert) y 
    from tst_result_main
```

Comment: Do `order by y, m` instead. (When SELECT DISTINCT only select list items can be specified in the ORDER BY.)

Answer (score 2):

having not aggregation function you should use distinct clause and not group by

```
select DISTINCT
EXTRACT(month from datetime_insert) m
, EXTRACT(year from datetime_insert) y 
from tst_result_main
 order by y, m
```